# How to derive differential gradient descent from cost function using matrix calculus?

Tags: matrix-calculus, gradient-descent

I am new to matrix calculus and I hope you can help me with this question!

I’m trying to derive the update law for gradient descent to minimize a cost function
$$j(\mathbf{X}) = \frac{1}{2} \mathbf{e}^T(\mathbf{X}) \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{X})$$
with $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{b}, \mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. First I calculate the gradient of $j$ w.r.t. a vectorized $\mathbf{x} := \operatorname{vec} \mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^{nk}$
$$\nabla_\mathbf{x} j(\mathbf{X}) = \left(\frac{\partial j}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^T = \left(\frac{\partial \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{X})}{\partial \mathbf{x}}\right)^T \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{X}).$$
For $\mathbf{e}$ it is known that
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{X}(s), s)}{\mathrm{d}s} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^T(s) \mathbf{b}.$$
Now I try to somehow derive the gradient using the chain rule
$$\nabla_\mathbf{x} j(\mathbf{X}) = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{X}(s), s)}{\mathrm{d}s} \frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}(s)}\right)^T \mathbf{e}
= \left(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^T(s) \mathbf{b} \frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}(s)}\right)^T \mathbf{e} 
= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}(s)}\right)^T \operatorname{Tr}\left(\mathbf{X}^T(s) \mathbf{b} \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{A}\right)
= \left(\frac{\mathrm{d} s}{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{x}(s)}\right)^T \mathbf{x}^T(s) \operatorname{vec}\left(\mathbf{b} \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{A}\right)
=\ ...?$$
The update law for $\mathbf{X}$ is stated as
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{X}}{\mathrm{d} s} = - \mathbf{\Gamma} \mathbf{b} \mathbf{e}^T \mathbf{A}$$
where $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ is a diagonal $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ matrix of update rates.

**I don’t understand how the update law (last equation) can be derived from the gradient (second to last equation). Could anyone please help me? Thank you so much in advance!**

Comment: What exactly is your error function $e\left(\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{s})\right) = ?$

Comment: @user550103 My error fuction is $\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{X}(s)) = \mathbf{e}(s_0) + \int_{\bar s = s_0}^{s} \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X}^T(s) \mathbf{b}\ \mathrm{d}\bar s$ with some constant $s_0$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\B{\Big}\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}\def\P#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}$Using
the given expression for the error function, calculate its differential
$$\eqalign{
e &= e_0 + A\L(\small\int_{X_0}^{X} dX\R)^Tb 
\quad\implies\quad
\color{red}{de = A\,dX^Tb} \\
}$$
Calculate the differential of the cost function and its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
j &= \tfrac 12e:e \\
dj &= e:\color{red}{de} \\
 &= e:\color{red}{A\,dX^Tb} \\
 &= e^T:b^TdX\,A^T \\
 &= be^TA:dX \\
\p{j}{X}
 &= be^TA  &\quad\big({\rm gradient}\big) \\
}$$
Now use an iterative gradient-descent method to calculate the optimal $X$
$$\eqalign{
X_{k+1} &= X_k - \lambda_k\Big(be^T_kA\Big) \\
}$$
where the scalar $\lambda_k>0$ is the *step-length* which minimizes the cost function for the $k^{th}$ iteration. The initial value (at $k=0$) of $X$ is likely $\,X_0=X(s_0),\,$ or it could be a random matrix.

Apparently, your textbook proposes to replace the standard **scalar** step-length with a matrix
$$\lambda_kI \to \Gamma_k \\\\$$

---

In the preceeding, a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
}$$
The properties of the trace function allow the terms in such a product to be rearranged in various ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A = B^T:A^T \\
CA:B &= C:BA^T = A:C^TB \\
}$$

Comment: Thank you, @greg, for your answer and your hint to the Frobenius product! This product and using a differential instead of a derivative form make the calculation much more compact!  So is it correct to say that I had missed that differentiating the iterative $X_{k+1} = X_k - \lambda \nabla j$ w.r.t. $s$ (as in **s**tep?) leads to $\partial X/\partial s = - \lambda\ \partial/\partial s \nabla j$, which cancels the $\partial s$ in my last expression of the gradient?

Comment: In order to confirm the expression for $\frac{\partial X}{\partial s}$ you'll need to tell me what $X(s)$ looks like. I used Leibniz's Rule to calculate $de$ in my post, but I did so _assuming_ that you made a typo in your previous definition. So it would also be helpful if you restated that expression, too. And do it in an update to your question, not in a comment,  because it's difficult to type/edit/read the comments on this site.